SVG from Inkscape invisible in QGIS
Can someone versed in SVG check the following SVG I made in Inkscape and tell me why it doesn't show in QGIS? It's invisible both in selection pane (although its name appears in the selection pane) and in the canvas when selected.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   width="3mm"
   height="1.5000814mm"
   viewBox="0 0 3 1.5000814"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg1069"
   inkscape:version="1.1.1 (3bf5ae0d25, 2021-09-20)"
   sodipodi:docname="proba_1.svg"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="namedview1071"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pagecheckerboard="0"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:zoom="20.496745"
     inkscape:cx="7.0011116"
     inkscape:cy="14.685258"
     inkscape:window-width="2560"
     inkscape:window-height="1506"
     inkscape:window-x="-11"
     inkscape:window-y="-11"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1" />
  <defs
     id="defs1066" />
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(-19.473208,-0.67009354)">
    <path
       style="fill:none;stroke:#ff0000;stroke-width:0.25;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:0, 0.3, 0, 0.05;stroke-dashoffset:0.25"
       id="path1820"
       sodipodi:type="arc"
       sodipodi:cx="20.973211"
       sodipodi:cy="2.1700964"
       sodipodi:rx="1.5000029"
       sodipodi:ry="1.5000029"
       sodipodi:start="3.1415403"
       sodipodi:end="6.2804102"
       sodipodi:open="true"
       sodipodi:arc-type="arc"
       d="M 19.473208,2.1701749 A 1.5000029,1.5000029 0 0 1 20.971091,0.67009504 1.5000029,1.5000029 0 0 1 22.473208,2.1659338" />
  </g>
</svg>

This is how it looks (I've resized the page in Inkscape to fit the selected object):

It's supposed to be only 3 mm wide, and it displays correctly in a Web browser and in MS Word, so I guess it's because of some quirk in QGIS.

Which bit of QGIS are you trying to load it into? As an item on a map layout, as a symbol for a point layer? Its not clear.

As a symbol for a point layer.

This looks like a bit of a clever hack to try and draw circles along a line by drawing a dash pattern where one of the dash segments is zero-length but with rounded line caps. All you see are the two rounded caps which look like a circle.
But I guess QGIS' rendering engine is going "This dash mark is length=0, so I'll not draw it" and in doing so doesn't draw the endcaps, so you see nothing.
If you change the length in the dash specification to something very small, just bigger than zero, you can still get the appearance of circles:

Change the style specification to set the first dash array stroke length to 0.00001 works for me (long line scroll thataway-> for everything):
 style="fill:none;stroke:#ff0000;stroke-width:0.25;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:0.00001, 0.3, 0, 0.05;stroke-dashoffset:0.25"

You can set this in the Inkscape XML editor which might be how you got it there in the first place...

Exactly right on all counts !!! Thank you so much :)
